Is Sakurai's derivation of the Lippmann-Schwinger equation correct?
I am using Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics 3rd ed. The following is from the beginning of chapter 6.
The defining equation for the $T$-matrix is
$$\langle \vec{k}' \lvert U_I(t, t_0) \lvert \vec{k} \rangle = \delta_{k'k} - \frac{i}{\hbar}T_{k'k}\int_{t_0}^t dt' e^{i\omega_{k'k} t' + \epsilon t'}. \tag{0}$$
The $(\vec{k}', \ \vec{k})$ component of the exact interaction time evolution operator with $t_0 \to -\infty$ is
\begin{equation}
    \langle \vec{k}' \lvert U_I(t,-\infty) \lvert \vec{k} \rangle = \delta_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} - \frac{i}{h} \sum_{\vec{k}''}V_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}''} \int_{-\infty}^t dt' e^{i\omega_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}''}t'}\langle \vec{k}'' \lvert U_I(t', -\infty) \lvert \vec{k}\rangle \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where we have inserted the completeness relation $\mathbb{I} = \sum_{\vec{k}''} \lvert \vec{k}'' \rangle \langle \vec{k}''\lvert$.
Substituting the defining equation of the $T$-matrix $(0)$ into the inner product in the integrand of $(1)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
    T_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} = V_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} + \sum_{\vec{k}''} V_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}''}\frac{T_{\vec{k}''\vec{k}}}{E_{\vec{k}} - E_{\vec{k}''} + i\hbar\epsilon}. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, we define the set of in-states $\lvert \psi^+ \rangle$ as the set of states satisfying the equation
\begin{equation}
    T_{\vec{k}'\vec{k}} = \langle \vec{k}' \lvert V \lvert  \psi^+ \rangle \quad \forall \lvert \vec{k}'\rangle. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Inserting $(3)$ into $(2)$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
    \langle \vec{k}' \lvert V \lvert  \psi^+ \rangle = \langle \vec{k}' \lvert V\lvert \vec{k} \rangle + \sum_{\vec{k}''} \langle \vec{k}' \lvert V\lvert \vec{k}'' \rangle \frac{\langle \vec{k}'' \lvert V \lvert  \psi^+ \rangle}{E_{\vec{k}} - E_{\vec{k}''} + i\hbar\epsilon} \\
    = \langle \vec{k}' \lvert V\lvert \vec{k} \rangle +  \langle \vec{k}' \lvert V\frac{1}{E_{\vec{k}} - H_0 + i\hbar\epsilon}V\lvert  \psi^+ \rangle \quad \forall \lvert \vec{k}'\rangle. \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
    V \lvert \psi^+ \rangle = V\lvert \vec{k} \rangle +  V\frac{1}{E_{\vec{k}} - H_0 + i\hbar\epsilon}V\lvert  \psi^+ \rangle. \tag{5}
\end{equation}
If $V$ is invertible, then we can invert it to obtain
\begin{equation}
    \lvert \psi^+ \rangle = \lvert \vec{k} \rangle +  \frac{1}{E_{\vec{k}} - H_0 + i\hbar\epsilon}V \lvert  \psi^+ \rangle. \tag{6}
\end{equation}
Equation $(6)$ is the Lippmann-Schwinger equation for in-states.
Sakurai states that because $(4)$ holds for all $\lvert \vec{k}'\rangle$, we obtain equation $(6)$. I remark that $(4)$ implies $(5)$.
Now, while solutions to $(6)$ are indeed solutions to $(5)$, solutions to $(5)$ are not necessarily solutions to $(6)$. Hence, Sakurai's derivation suggests that looking at just the Lippmann-Schwinger equations does not give all the in- and out-states.
If we wanted an equivalence of solution space between $(5)$ and $(6)$, we have to assume that $V$ is invertible. But, certainly $V$ is not always invertible!
So, is Sakurai's derivation just wrong or have I misunderstood a step in the derivation?

Please add the chapter, and it might help if you label your equation as in the book.

Your steps from Equation (4) to Equation (5) should take some care to separate the two appearances of $V$ and the identity operator. It should read as $V\frac1{\text{stuff with } H_0}V$, and only then should you be able to see that every term can have a $V$ removed from the left. The difference is only an arbitrary addition of states that $V$ sends to zero, and we can just impose the condition that those states are not added or something. So Sakurai is correct that it actually implies Equation (6), with at most trivial caveats like that.

@naturallyInconsistent I agree with the first part. Perhaps it is worth to expand your second into an answer? I don't quite get it, tbh. Do you mean to say that $V(x-y)=0$ has the solutions $x=y+a$, where $a$ is in the kernel of $V$?

@TobiasFünke that is what I am saying, indeed. I was rushing out for a movie so I didnt really have the time to type it up
